# Issue with POST request parameters null with large payload on Java servlet

Tags: java, http, servlets, post, tomcat7

I have a Java servlet that takes a POST request with 2 body parameters, one of which is very large (about 6.8MB). When I send the request and use the HttpServletRequest.getParameter method for the parameters the values are null. When I test with a small parameter (just a few characters) the parameter is read correctly. I have tried setting the maxPostSize variable in my tomcat7 server.xml file to "0" so there is no limit and restarted the server but the issue is persisting. Does anyone know what would cause the parameters to be null?

Comment: No, the parameters are simply urlencoded in the body

Comment: Oh, sorry, I completel misunderstood and somehow read this as being a file upload (also encoded in the body, but different issue). Sorry!

Comment: I saw that post earlier, I have already tried to change the maxPostSize so that shouldn't be the issue. There is no exception or message indicating that post body is too large, the parameter values are just null.